# python socket client error

Tags: python, sockets

i have another question similiar to this about a server script if you could answer that to it will be great.

```
import socket   
import sys  
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error , msg:
    print ('Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1])
    sys.exit();

print ('Socket Created')
```

in my server program i set the port to 8888 and the name to ""

```
host = ''
port = 8888
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()
    
print ('Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip)
```

## Connect to remote server

```
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print ('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

try :
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    print ('Send failed')
    sys.exit()

print ('Message send successfully')

reply = s.recv(4096)


print (reply)



s.close()
```

it gives an error on the exept socket.error , msg:
it highlightes  the apostrophe, when i deleted it , python highlited the msg.
and when i deleted that, it gave an error but did not tell anything

Comment: Unless you're using a *really* old version of Python, `except socket.error , msg` should be `except socket.error as msg`...

Comment: It seems that you have created server socket, but don't listen on it.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the following exception handling syntax:

```
except socket.error as msg:
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions